# How to create a for loops using an external textfile in Ruby

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm trying to loop through the list VulnsList.txt which contains multiple lines.

When i run the script below it fails, Now if i remove all lines in the list except for one, the code will complete.

I believe the code is not looping through the list line for line.

```
File.open("VulnsList.txt") do |f|
     f.each_line do |vuln|
           rsn = "Other" 
           reporter_comments = "This exception has been approved for 60 days."
           assets = nsc.group_assets(ag)            
           assets.each do |asset|    
           exc = VulnException.new(vuln, VulnException::Scope::ALL_INSTANCES_ON_A_SPECIFIC_ASSET, rsn)    
           exc.asset_id = asset.id    
           exc.save(nsc, reporter_comments)
        end 
    end
end
```

This is the contents of the file:

generic-icmp-timestamp

jenkins-2018-04-11_cve-2018-1000169

jenkins-2018-04-11_cve-2018-1000170

This is the error i recieve:

```
Retrying the request due to undefined method `sub' for nil:NilClass. If you see
this message please open an Issue on Github with the error.



Retrying the request due to undefined method `sub' for nil:NilClass. If you see
this message please open an Issue on Github with the error.



Retrying the request due to undefined method `sub' for nil:NilClass. If you see
this message please open an Issue on Github with the error.



Retrying the request due to undefined method `sub' for nil:NilClass. If you see
this message please open an Issue on Github with the error.



Retrying the request due to undefined method `sub' for nil:NilClass. If you see
this message please open an Issue on Github with the error.

Traceback (most recent call last):
        9: from Exceptions_by_Asset_Group - Copy.rb:48:in `<main>'
        8: from Exceptions_by_Asset_Group - Copy.rb:48:in `open'
        7: from Exceptions_by_Asset_Group - Copy.rb:49:in `block in <main>'
        6: from Exceptions_by_Asset_Group - Copy.rb:49:in `each_line'
        5: from Exceptions_by_Asset_Group - Copy.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in <
main>'
        4: from Exceptions_by_Asset_Group - Copy.rb:54:in `each'
        3: from Exceptions_by_Asset_Group - Copy.rb:57:in `block (3 levels) in <
main>'
        2: from D:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/nexpose-7.2.1/lib/nexpose
/vuln_exception.rb:230:in `save'
        1: from D:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/nexpose-7.2.1/lib/nexpose
/connection.rb:124:in `execute'
D:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/nexpose-7.2.1/lib/nexpose/api_request.rb:
148:in `execute': NexposeAPI: Action failed: Nexpose service returned an unrecog
nized response: "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>\n
<Failure error-code=\"-1\">\n    <Message>Error encountered, unable to fulfill r
equest.</Message>\n    <Exception>\n        <Message></Message>\n        <Stackt
race></Stacktrace>\n    </Exception>\n</Failure>\n" (Nexpose::APIError)
jenkins-2018-05-09_cve-2018-1000192
```

Comment: _it fails_ is vague. What happens? An unexpected result? An error? What is the error message? How does the file look like?

Comment: Please post a link to the file or sample data of the file. You're also missing another end in the snippet you posted but I suspect you just missed it when posting your question not in your code.

Comment: The code you show us is missing and `end` statement, can you correct it?

Comment: @Martinos If the code is missing `end` statements, then the question needs to be closed because it has syntax errors.

Comment: The end statement is in the original code. The problem im having is making this script iterator each line. When i tested the script all the lines from that list printed at once.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I added .chomp to the variable and it worked!

Thanks

```
exc = VulnException.new(vuln, VulnException::Scope::ALL_INSTANCES_ON_A_SPECIFIC_ASSET, rsn)

exc = VulnException.new(vuln.chomp, VulnException::Scope::ALL_INSTANCES_ON_A_SPECIFIC_ASSET, rsn)
```